# Wordpress when password updated user is logout

Tags: wordpress

I have change password at front-end and i m using wp_user_update function,but when user change password it have been log out. the problem is that my old cookies is not updated,so how to update password without log out.have any idea?..

```
global $wpdb, $current_user;

$user_id =  $current_user->ID;
wp_update_user(array('ID'=>$user_id,'user_pass'=>$_POST['user_pass']));
```

Comment: it is not possible, you cant play with current cookies along with changing password, because your page is going to refresh after changing the password

Comment: i think you dont know about wordpress function wp_update_user

Comment: ohk if you know better than close the topic.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by [Aaron Forgue](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/updating-wpuser-password-logs-out-user) at the WordPress Support is 3 years old, but might be interesting. I had to change the `$wpdb->query()` to make it work:

```
global $wpdb;

$profile_id = $_POST['prof_id'];
$username = $_POST['log_name'];
$password = $_POST['wachtwoord'];
$md5password = wp_hash_password($password);

// You may want to use $wpdb->prepare() here. As it stands, malicous code could be passed in via $_POST['prof_id'] or $_POST['log_name']
$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( 
        "
            UPDATE $wpdb->users SET user_pass = %s WHERE ID = %d
        ", 
        $md5password, 
        $profile_id 
    ) );

// Here is the magic:
wp_cache_delete($profile_id, 'users');
wp_cache_delete($username, 'userlogins'); // This might be an issue for how you are doing it. Presumably you'd need to run this for the ORIGINAL user login name, not the new one.
wp_logout();
wp_signon(array('user_login' => $username, 'user_password' => $password));
```

Credits go to this plugin for the above trick: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/change-password-e-mail/

As mentioned by [Robahas](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp_signon-not-working), make sure that this code is run *before* headers are sent, else the `wp_signon()` will not work and the user will be logged out anyway.